# Selenium - Stopping server

Tags: selenium

Selenium server (ver. 2) has stopped working for me for unknown reasons (see [Selenium (RC) hangs when started from Python test](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/1278/selenium-rc-stops-working)). I'd like to stop Selenium sever and restart it. When I enter "http://localhost:4444/selenium-server/driver/?cmd=shutDown" into the address bar of a browser on the machine running Selenium server, I get a blank screen in the browser window. If I try to `wget` that address, the command line says no data received. If I run:
`ps aux | grep sel`
It shows that Selenium server is still running. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Windows, see if this post helps you:

https://superuser.com/questions/52159/kill-a-process-with-a-specific-command-line-from-command-line

For UNIX / Linux, find the process Id (PID) corresponding to the selenium server, and kill the process

Comment: Ah, thanks. Didn't know why I didn't think of that. I finally just started selenium server on another port...